# Google Analytics Event Tracking not traking

Tags: google-analytics

Im trying to track Contact form 7 Submission, the settings are as follows:

```
Goal set-up = custom goal-type=event;
Goal description = CF7 Submission
Goal Detail: Category=CF7 Form – Action=Submission – Label=Contact EU
```

i pasted this code into functions.php:

[image: Funtions.php]

website: siiengine.com

Comment: All your quotes are wrong. Do not use curly quotes, use the standard form instead: `'` and `"`.

Comment: My Code are like below(I think the quotes only change cause i copy the code to notepad first):


document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    if ( '3907' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
ga('send', 'event', 'CF7 Form', 'Submission', 'Trial EU');
}
 else if ( '3984' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
ga('send', 'event', 'CF7 Form', 'Submission', 'White paper EU');
}
  else if ( '373' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
ga('send', 'event', 'CF7 Form', 'Submission', 'Contact EU');
}

Comment: Then update your question with the code that you have actually used. That's much more readable than a comment. :)

Comment: I just did sorry for the misleading code.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would comment all that JavaScript out and simply do a `console.log('This Function is Running...')` to see if it is actually firing or not.

That being said, how I would approach this is to actually put this in a JavaScript file and simply enqueue it along with the rest of my styles/scripts. You can even have it conditionally load on the specific page it's bring used on. So, using the enqueue function in [_s](https://github.com/Automattic/_s/blob/master/functions.php) as an example:

```
/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
function _s_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( '_s-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( '_s-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), '20151215', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( '_s-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20151215', true );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }

    if ( is_page( 'contact-me' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'cf7-tracker', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/cf7tracker.js', array(), '', true );
    }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', '_s_scripts' );
```

Comment: I testet this code with alert messages(not on the live site) where it worked fine so the the code gets executive when a form is send.

Comment: Ok. I'll keep my answer up for reference purposes, but I guess it no longer applies. Wasn't sure if it was the JavaScript itself that was causing the issue or the action not firing. I would recommend you do implement a conditional enqueue though rather than putting `<script>` elements directly in though.